# Назначение прав на файл с++

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

Пытаюсь добавить права на файл:

```
    AddAccessRule(gcnew FileSystemAccessRule(@"MyDomain\MyAccessAccount", FileSystemRights::ReadData, AccessControlType::Allow));
```

Возникает ошибка unknown character '0x40'  по причине символа @.
Как это исправить?

Comment: Непростой вы язык для себя выбрали. По мне уж если C++, так нормальный C++. Уж если CLI, так C#. А Managed C++ это какой-то странный уродец, продукт противоестественной связи. И не факт, что у него в будущем какая-то перспектива есть.

Comment: Символ `@` перед строковыми литералами можно ставить только в C#. В C++/CLI такого синтаксиса нет. Уберите этот символ, а внутри строки используйте `\\ `.